# How much aged cheese is needed in a cheese mix to require waiting 6 hours?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

According to Remo in [Shulchan Aruch Yorah De'ah 89:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.89.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as referred in this [OU article](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/aged-cheese-list/), people should wait 6 hours after eating hard cheese.

Let's say someone eats a type of cheese that is partially hard cheese & partially non hard cheese. (The mix was intentionally done, incidentally, for explicit purpose of selling it this way. Let's say the cheese is called "Parmerican" - parmesan (aged) + processed "American") Does the person need to wait 6 hours because he ate **some** hard cheese? How much hard cheese would require waiting 6 hours - does it follow the same concept of "batul beshishim" (less than 1/60) as with milk accidentally mixed into a meat dish (i.e., less than 1/60 is nullified)? Is the amount based on majority (more than 50% hard cheese in the mix means 6 hours) or is there some other measurement in this mix that requires a 6-hour wait?

Comment: Is this mixture melted together, or is it just a dry mix with distinct pieces?

Comment: @Yishai I can see why you're asking about melting, b/c I noticed in the OU article some opinion stating that melting destroys the "hard cheese" properties. Let's assume for this case, that the cheese was mixed as a solid. However, as far as recognition, you can make this part of your answer. Would there be differences between one hunk of cheese made from both or if it was a pile of grated cheese from both Parmesan and soft cheese mixed together so you can see which was which b/c of each cheese's distinctive color?

Comment: @Yishai if it's melted, then it's no longer considered "hard." You no longer need to wait until it is re-hardened. Not exactly sure of a source, but it was brought up in this exact context during a conversation I had not too long ago...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky IIRC, the OU article that I placed in my question mentions that there is an opinion stating that melting nullifies the "aged" properties. See also, my comment / response to Yishai. For simplicity, assume that the cheese "mix" is not melted.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, there is such an opinion, but it is not universal.

Comment: That opinon is of the Yad Yehuda and there is a posek who holds by it.

Comment: @sam for example, the CRC and OU hold of it http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/kashrus-corner/185010/crc-kosher-top-ten-questions-for-july-2012.html https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/the-halachot-of-waiting-between-meals/ I don't really understand why one would want to be machmir on such a practice which is already built on chumra on top of chumra on a minhag.

Comment: I know a very  big posek as well who allows it

Comment: I just checked the Shulchan Halevi(Rav Belsky) it seems he allows also

Comment: The Rema (in 89:2) brings both options: some are strict and some are lenient, regarding waiting 6hrs after eating hard cheese.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of bitul b'shishim should certainly apply here. The idea is that any amount less than 1/60th of the volume of the mixture is undetectable ([source](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-ABISSELBITUL.htm)), and therefore considered to not exist.

Bitul b'rov (nullification by 50%) would not apply in this case as that only works for identical foods. For example, if two non-kosher chicken legs are accidentally mixed up with 3 identical kosher chicken legs, all 5 legs are permitted (do not do this in practice without consulting your rabbi). This would not apply in this case since the hard cheese is clearly not identical to the soft cheese.

Therefore, any cheese mixture that is less than 1/60 hard cheese should not require waiting while any cheese mixture that is more than 1/60 hard cheese would require waiting.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced. First, the rules of 1/60 apply to meat / milk & kosher / non-kosher. I'm not sure if it applies here, as they are the same item - cheese - just different types of cheese. Second, even if you would follow the 1/60 rule, according to the article there are 2 areas where it is NOT nullified - when intentionally mixed (I guess I was unclear about this, as I didn't consider it an issue; I'll edit), and Davar Shebeminyan. Aged & non-aged cheese are usually sold separately. The mix is unusual.

Comment: Bittul by hetter bihetter?

Comment: @user6591 Why not? My understanding is that the reason we purchase milk _before_ pesach is because any chametz that is in the milk is batel b'shishim while it is still permitted.

Comment: @DanF If it's the same item, _al achat kamah v'kamah_ bitul b'shishim should work. Nonetheless, I really don't think you could say it's the same thing. As for your cases where nullification doesn't work: the intentional mixture is called "אין מבטלין איסור לכתחילה" (as mentioned in the article). That is a separate isur to intentionally rely on bitul b'shishim l'chatchila to nullify something asur. There is nothing asur about mixing kinds of cheese. As for the second case, I think you have misunderstood what a דבר שבמנין is. When the article says, (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) "If something is usually sold individually, it does not become batel," that does not refer to things that are not sold together with other things. It's referring to things that are sold in whole number increments of the thing (in other words, you go to the store and buy 4 pomegranates, not 1 pound of pomegranates [even though the price might be by the pound, you would never divide up a pomegranate to get to exactly one pound]). The fact that hard cheese and soft cheese are sold separately is irrelevant. Milk and beef are also sold separately and we know bitul works by them.

Comment: "This would not apply in this case since the hard cheese is clearly not identical to the soft cheese." Except in this case the two are indistinguishable parts of the whole, so you very well could call them identical. I'm not convinced we can't use bittul birov here.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Bitul b'rov only applies when you're talking about discrete food items like the 5 chicken legs I mentioned.  It doesn't apply to mixtures.

Comment: Aderaba, bitul birov is the de'oraysa RULE, but Chazal instituted bitul bashishim to handle "forbidden mixtures."

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky So you don't hold of derabanans?

Comment: @Daniel that's not at all my point. Do you have evidence that bittul 60 exists in NONISSURIM (such as this one)? I can't find anything that shows that Chazal applied it outside a direct issur.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59752/how-much-aged-cheese-is-needed-in-a-cheese-mix-to-require-waiting-6-hours/59756?noredirect=1#comment160142_59756

Comment: So... self referential? and chametz/kitniyot is EXACTLY the issue of a forbidden mixture. FWIW: Your understanding of that issue is slightly flawed, because the principle is that we can be ACTIVELY MEVATEL the chametz in the milk through "kol chamirah" BEFORE pesach, but not ON pesach. Batel bashishim would be just as relevant during if it was the operating mechanic before.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I believe you are incorrect about that. [See here](http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=52020&highlight=shishim). Chametz before Pesach is not assur, but it is mevatel b'shishim.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky For a stronger reference than the one I cited above, see [the OK](http://www.ok.org/v1/Content.asp?ID=73)

Comment: That particular site regularly offers advice outside current orthodox praxis (such as not requiring hechsherim for manufactured foods "if the ingredients are kosher"). I'm not certain we can rely upon their assessment of the relevant halachot in this case. We can be "actively mevatel" chametz BECAUSE it is batel bashishim, but only do so due to the impending issur. Kol Chamirah is a resolution of the catch-22 of pre-emptively being mevatel something BEFORE it becomes an issur, which is not something normally done. It's an exception to the rule you're trying to invoke

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky The OK is "outside the current orthodox praxis"? You need to back up your claim that bitul b'shishim only allows active nullification and doesn't cause nullification on its own. That's not how bitul b'shishim normally works and I don't know why I should think it's how it works in this case. Please show me a reference that if I were to purchase some milk after saying Kol Chamirah and before Pesach starts that it would be assur for me.

Comment: I was referring to kashrut.org, not the OK. I will look up the other link. Quote from the latter: "Therefore, ***if the milk was in the possession of the Jew before noon on erev Pesach,*** any chametz in the milk is batel" Specifically because that is WHEN we engage in the PROCESS OF BITTUL, and NOT because it was "already batel." ***Otherwise, there would be no requirement for it to be owned by a Jew in order for it to be batel.***

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky All the Kol Chamirah does is make it so that you don't own the chametz anymore. It doesn't help if you eat it. You can say Kol Chamirah all you want, but if one of those bread crumbs that you nullified falls into your food, it's still assur.

Comment: @Daniel Actually Chametz is considered Issur even before Pesach https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%93 Isaac's question is better than you seem to think.