# Source for waiting between milk and meat?

Tags: halacha, minhag, time, meat-and-milk

There is a widespread custom to wait 30 min between (soft) cheese and meat. What is the origin and source of this custom?

Comment: You know this is wide spread how? The basic halacha only requires rinsing one's mouth from dairy to meat. The zohar speaks of a longer time not 30 minutes but an hour

Comment: Can you source that this custom exists? And that it's widespread?

Comment: The Zohar,I believe it's brought in the Taz,the actual custom is 1 hour

Comment: I have only seen this by hard cheeses https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/are-all-fromages-created-equal-waiting-between-cheese-and-meat/

Comment: the source for cheese is Maharam of Rothenburg. He writes that when he saw people waiting after cheese he thought this represented dangerous sectarianism. Eventually he realized that cheese can get stuck in your mouth and that the practice is permissible. eventually the practice evolved from permissible to obligatory.

Comment: @mevaqesh Did it really? The Rama says we aren't Mocheh if you don't wait. Some have the practice, but if you don't, so what?

Comment: @DoubleAA They: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/dairy-that-you-have-to-wait-6-hours-after-eating-it/8170#8170, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52781/what-defines-hard-cheese, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59752/how-much-aged-cheese-is-needed-in-a-cheese-mix-to-require-waiting-6-hours, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59835/length-of-time-for-waiting-for-hard-cheese-proportionate-to-the-length-of-time-i, seem to think so

Comment: @mevaqesh So in the last 30 years we see a somewhat known personal custom being enshrined as a Takkana Derabanan. Is that really indicative of a meaningful Halakhic change or just a modern tendency towards oversimplification, monolithicity and stringency?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9222&st=&pgnum=105 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11583&st=&pgnum=140

Answer (score 3):

[This article from OU](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/the-halachot-of-waiting-between-meals/) gives the source as follows:

> **Must one wait after a dairy meal before eating meat?**
>
> After eating dairy, one can eat meat so long as he does the following:
>   1. cleanses his mouth, 2. rinses his mouth, and 3. washes his hands. Some also have the practice of reciting the necessary berachot after
>   the dairy meal, waiting, and then reciting new berachot for the meat
>   meal. The need and permissibility of reciting berachot in this case is
>   a subject of halachic controversy. One may clean his mouth by eating
>   or drinking something pareve. Any solid pareve food other than dates,
>   raw flour and greens can be used. Steps 1-3 may be done in any order.
>   One must wash his hands and clean his mouth even if he feels that they
>   are clean. An exception for washing one’s hands is made for one who
>   used utensils and had absolutely no physical contact with the food.
>
> If the meal to follow consists of poultry and not beef, there is no
>   need for one to cleanse his mouth or wash his hands. (This is because
>   mixing poultry with dairy is only rabbinically prohibited.) **Although
>   there is no halachic requirement to wait after eating dairy before
>   eating meat, some wait an hour or half an hour, based on a statement
>   found in the Zohar. (The Zohar’s exact wording can be found in the
>   commentary of the Vilna Gaon on [Yoreh Deah
>   89:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%98).**
>   {The link is to Yoreh Deah but not to the Vilna Gaon and the halocho is in 89:2}.  In all cases,
>   one must be sure to use a new tablecloth or eating surface and to use
>   new utensils.

---

The links for the sources printed in the Shulchan aruch

The gra (vilna gaon) is probably [89.6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4224) (and in 89.11 he explains that it goes both ways)
the shach brings the same Zohar [89.16](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4225)