# Where is the source for waiting an hour after eating dairy?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, meat-and-milk, zohar

There are those (eg. Chabad) who have a custom to wait an hour after eating dairy before eating meat.

I was told that the source is in the Zohar.

Can anyone point to the exact origin of this custom?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71649/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Zohar that’s referred to is in [Parashat Mishpatim 125a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar.2.125a.9?lang=bi) which talks about eating meat and milk בשעתא חדא, which can be understood as “within one hour of each other”.

Comment: ... but can also be understood as "at the same time"

Comment: @DoubleAA אין הכי נמי ולפע״ד הכי מסתברא טפי

Comment: It says same hour OR same meal. Now if "same hour" really means "at the same time together" then the Zohar merely need say "not in the same meal". Why say both expressions?

Comment: It should also be noted that the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 89:2 has the Rema bringing down this Zohar as the source. See there the Shach who quotes sefer Metzaref L'Chochmah who learns possibly that the Zohar holds one hour either from milk to meat or meat to milk. The Shach himself accepts that as pshat.

Comment: @David Lo Zo Af Zo Ketani. This is obvious. Seriously is there any other place in the canon of Jewish literature where בשעתא חדא means within 60 minutes of each other? Maybe it could also mean in the same o'clock and dairy at 3:59 can be followed by meat at 4:01.

Comment: @David the Rama you cite is explicitly about hard cheese. Why would he not prohibit after all dairy if that is what he thought? Really he's just rounding off the hard cheese prohibition to include poultry as well, unlike Maharam, in light of the dominance of the Ramban's school of thought on poultry. In fact the Rama is just citing the Beit Yosef who cites this Zohar explicitly using it to justify people not eating meat after cheese *in the same meal*. Nothing about waiting an hour. ויש מחמירין על עצמם שלא לאכול בשר אחר גבינה בסעודה אחת מפני שכתוב בספר הזוהר